# PowerShell - Invoke-WebRequest - Relative URI not supported when using -Proxy

Tags: powershell, proxy

i try to access websites through a proxy.

I tried the following:

```
$mycredentials = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri heise.de -Proxy proxySrv -ProxyCredential $mycredentials
```

> Invoke-WebRequest : Dieser Vorgang wird für einen relativen URI nicht
>   unterstützt. In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
>   + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri heise.de -Proxy proxySrv -Prox ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Translation of error to English:

> Invoke-WebRequest : This operation is not supported for a relative URI. In line: 1 character: 1
>   + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri heise.de -Proxy proxySrv -Prox ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

If I attempt the command without the Proxy setting I get an error from our proxy.

Can you help figure out why?

Comment: Can you try to full qualify the URI like "https ://heise.de"

Comment: same error, also tryed proxy IP instead of name
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ht"tps://heise.de -Proxy 192.168.222.222:8080 -ProxyCredential $mycredentials

Answer (score 18):

The relative URL being complained about is the **proxy** URL, not the target URL. Replace:

```
-Proxy 192.168.222.222:8080
```

with

```
-Proxy http://192.168.222.222:8080
```

(or `https` if appropriate) and you should find the error goes away